# How to implement an archive filter page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, search, filtering

I am searching for a way/tutorial to implement a filter method in WordPress.
Here is an example of what I need to accomplish.
[example](https://ww1.lu/collection?lang=en)

I need to put the filter method to right and show the filter results to the left using different categories where i can search for categories as well.

I am not sure how this works in wordpress, do i need to use a certain plugin? or is there a way to merge JavaScript code into it? then how can i link this code as a page to wordpress?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/

The output won't be exactly the same but you can achieve 80% of what you want to achieve.
You can see here the demo of the plugin: https://demo.searchandfilter.com/movies/

Comment: You can also use FacetWP plugin https://facetwp.com/
Its a paid plugin

Comment: Thank you guys, I will check them both and see which one would give me the desired results